# "пройти" and "пройтись"

Tags: значения

What's the difference between "пройти" and "пройтись"? Are they completely interchangeable? Are there any situations, in which only one could be used, but not  the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're mostly non-interchangeable.

*in physical sense*

**`пройти`** (impf `проходить`) - to walk/pass by/through

> Он прошёл мимо охранника.
>
> Войдя в квартиру, он прошёл в гостинную.
>
> Чтобы попасть на другой берег, нужно пройти по мосту.
>
> Легче верблюду пройти сквозь игольное ушко, чем богачу войти в царствие небесное. *(Евангелие от Матфея 19:24)*

**`пройтись`** (impf `прохаживаться`) - to take a walk, to stroll (usually implies to and fro and in an easy pace)

> Налетела грусть, ну что ж, пойду пройдусь. *(А. Розенбаум "Налетела
>   грусть")*
>
> Манекенщица прошлась туда и обратно по подиуму.

About the same difference can be observed between **`проехать`** and **`проехаться`**, **`пробежать`** and **`пробежаться`** with the only exception being that to these reflexive verbs an easy pace of movement doesn't apply.

*in figurative sense*

**`пройти`** (impf `проходить`) - to cease/to go away/to pass off (a condition, a state); to pass (by)/to elapse; to study as a part of school curriculum; to take place; to undergo/to go through

> У меня прошёл кашель.
>
> Прошла уже неделя с тех пор, как у меня прошёл кашель.
>
> По литературе мы сейчас проходим "Войну и мир", "Обломова" уже прошли.
>
> Сейчас в стране проходят выборы. В городе проходят обыски. В Польше проходит конференция ООН по вопросам изменения климата. В Токийском аэропорту Ханэда проходят испытания автобуса с автономным управлением.
>
> Новый метод лечения рака успешно прошёл испытания.

**`пройтись`** (colloquial, impf isn't used) - to look/talk through / address several points/items; to rebuke several people; to lambast

> Мы ещё раз прошлись по пунктам договора.
>
> После того, как отдел не успел в срок закончить проект, на собрании
>   начальник прошёлся по каждому исполнителю.
>
> Невзоров жёстко прошёлся по пропагандистке Скабеевой.

Comment: Are you sure they are "completely non-interchangeable"? Are these two different: "Тебе нужно пройти разок по этой мостовой", "Тебе нужно пройтиСЬ разок по этой мостовой"?

Comment: @brilliant yeah, maybe imperative and pefrective past/future tense are isolated cases where they can be more or less interchangeable in the sense of walking for the sake of walking... so i mitigated my remark

Comment: @brilliant sure